# When CopyQueueLength is high, how do I control which server is the source?

Tags: exchange-2010, replication, bandwidth, wide-area-network, dag

When I have a DAG with copies spread all over the world, and the initial seeding is already complete, how does Exchange control which server is used to fulfill the outstanding CopyQueueLength logs that need to be copied?

How can I control this?

The reason this is important is because some databases have a local same site (1000 Gig connection) and others are on an MPLS /WAN connection